# React Routes not showing when using Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create routes for my site. Each component renders when placed without the route marker. But i can not get this to work including the routes. any help please as im reading switcher has been replaced for Routes but still facing the issue.

> Blockquote

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 
    "react-router-dom"
import Navbar from './Navbar.js';
import Header from './Header';
import About from './About';
import Contact from './Contact';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Services from './Services.js';


function App() {
  return (<Router>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Header} />
        <Route path="/" component={Services} />
        <Route path="/" component={Footer} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
    </Routes>
    <Footer />
    </Router>

  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`component` is also replaced by `element` in RRDv6 and `exact` is deprecated.

```
<Route path="/contact" element={< Contact />} />
```

Here is the running code https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-swartz-ikqdn

Comment: You can green tick and upvote to mark this as an answer and close the question.

Comment: You misunderstood the meaning of both the green tick and the concept of closing a question. The tick is for that among several answer (all of which are answers...) which OP subjectively finds most helpful, which among other things does not mean "correct". Closing a question is for those questions which are not really questions according to StackOverflow rules and concepts ( [ask] ) or are not answerable for various reasons.